# Prefix or append a string to meta_title, meta_key, meta_description in category page

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

Category page `meta_title`, `meta_key` and `meta_description` tags come from the table `ps_category_lang`.

```
mysql> select * from ps_category_lang limit 1;
+-------------+---------+---------+-------+-------------+--------------+------------+---------------+------------------+
| id_category | id_shop | id_lang | name  | description | link_rewrite | meta_title | meta_keywords | meta_description |
+-------------+---------+---------+-------+-------------+--------------+------------+---------------+------------------+
|           1 |       1 |       1 | Raíz  |             | raiz         |            |               |                  |
+-------------+---------+---------+-------+-------------+--------------+------------+---------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is it possible to add a prefix (or suffix) to those three values, so it uses the information from the database but it appends or prefixs a certain value?

If so, what shall be needed to be done? I already have a custom module overriding the category page with extended template and controller.

Prestashop 1.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is by overriding the `/classes/controller/FrontController.php`, specifically the method `getTemplateVarPage()` in the code:

```
$page = array(
    'title' => '',
    'canonical' => $this->getCanonicalURL(),
    'meta' => array(
        'title' => $meta_tags['meta_title'],
        'description' => $meta_tags['meta_description'],
        'keywords' => $meta_tags['meta_keywords'],
        'robots' => 'index',
    ),
    'page_name' => $page_name,
    'body_classes' => $body_classes,
    'admin_notifications' => array(),
);
```

Here you could validate the current page and alterate it as your needs.

Answer (score 1):

for each standard controller in PrestaShop, you have a dedicated function in the `Meta` class, in your case, the `getCategoryMetas()` function that you can override and adapt to fit your needs.

You also can use [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018734/10276219) to rewrite the metas firstly computed in the `Meta::getCategoryMetas()` in `CategoryController::getTemplateVarPage()` function.

Good luck